# Fast calculation for sum of minterms in C++?

Tags: c++, math, boolean, logic, bit-manipulation

Assume we have a byte representing a [minterm sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form), where each bit represents a specific minterm for A, B, C. For example, ms=0x12 should represent

`F(a, b, c) = (A & (~B) & (~C)) | ((~A) & B & (~C))`

Here you can see a sum of two terms

`bit 2 is (~A) & B & (~C)`

`bit 4 is A & (~B) & (~C)`

However, when we have some terms summed, the final equation may be simplified, for example, 0xF0 represents a sum of 4 terms

`F(a, b, c) = (A & B & C) | (A & B & (~C)) | (A & (~B) & C) | (A & (~B) & (~C))`

which is then perfectly simplified to `F(a, b, c) = A`

What I am looking for is a C++ method that fast calculates `MintermSum(A, B, C, minterm)`
where A, B, C are byte values, and `minterm` is a minterm set represented as a byte.

Internally this function may look like

```
int MintermSum(int a, int b, int c, byte minterm)
{
    switch(minterm) {
         case 0:
             return 0;
         case 1:
             return (~a) & (~b) & (~c);
         case 2:
             return (~a) & (~b) & c;
         //.....
         case 0x12:
             return (a & (~b) & (~c)) | ((~a) & b & (~c));
         //..... lots of case's
         case 0xf0:
             return a;   // Simplified calculation
         //....
         case 0xff:
             return 1;
    }
}
```

I hope someone has already written this function, but I can't find it. May you help, please?

Comment: Asking for someone to write your code for you is off-topic.  Asking for library or third-party solution recommendations is also off-topic.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've posted?

Comment: @Jarod42 Right, (~a) & (~b) & (~c), my mistake.

Comment: *I hope someone has already written this function* -- I'm sure someone has implemented [Quine-Mccluskey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) in C++.  If not C++, glean the computation from whatever language the algorithm is implemented in.

Comment: `simd-everywhere` has an implantation of `VPTERNLOGD`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you friends, based on your recommendations and links I made my own implementation of minterm sum function, hopefully it will be useful for others.

https://github.com/Epsiloncool/minterm-sum